# Is there a way to filter a text string to get values that are NOT LIKE a pattern?

Tags: r, regex, string, dplyr

I want things that are not like a string. I had a look at [this](https://suzan.rbind.io/2018/02/dplyr-tutorial-3/) and noted:

This works for likes:

```
library(datasets)
library(dplyr)

msleep %>% 
  select(name, sleep_total) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(tolower(name), pattern = "mouse"))
```

But this doesn't work for not like:

```
msleep %>% 
  select(name, sleep_total) %>% 
  filter(str_detect(tolower(name), pattern != "mouse"))
```

I get this:

```
Error in filter_impl(.data, quo) : 
  Evaluation error: object 'pattern' not found.
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted in the comments, I worked out an answer:

```
msleep %>% 
  select(name, sleep_total) %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(tolower(name), pattern = "mouse"))
```

`!str_detect` was the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!mouse).*$
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that go in the pattern section?